# How to combine multiple Javascript files from different folder in a single file?

Tags: javascript, command-line, npm, browserify, bootstrap-4

i have lots of JavaScript files in different folders and want to add them to a master.js together. I have the following project structure:

```
/dist/js/master.js <-- Output file

/src/bootstrap-untouched/js <-- Bootstrap Plugins (alert.js, button.js etc.)
/src/js/plugins.js
/src/js/script.js
```

It would be good if I could activate and deactivate the individual bootstrap plugins. I do not want to use Grunt and Gulp. I use only the NPM.
I think that would have to somehow work with browserify and uglifyjs.

Comment: "I do not want to use Grunt and Gulp" :(

Answer (score 1):

In the source folder execute:

find . -name \*.js  -type f -exec cat {} \; > ~/master.js

That is all.

Comment: I had forgotten to say that it should go with the package.json. I want a task :-) When saving automatically master.js should be generated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've got some starter file (like `entry.js` - you can call it whatever you want actually).

In that case, this code should work:

> var b = require('browserify')();
>
> b.add('your entry js');
>
> b.transform('uglifyify');
>
> var indexjs = fs.createWriteStream('build/bundle.js');
>
> b.bundle().pipe(indexjs);